# Using `dplyr::case_when` to choose a function in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to use dplyr's `case_when` function to let me dynamically choose between functions.

For example, let's say I want to choose an average function and then call it:

```
average = function(.data, .avg){
    f = case_when(
        .avg == 'mean' ~ mean,
        .avg == 'median' ~ median,
    )
    f(.data)
}
```

Now, if I call this function, I get this error:

```
> average(c(1, 2), 'mean')
Error in value[[1]][rep(NA_integer_, m)] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

I don't think I'm doing anything wrong here, but `case_when` doesn't seem to want me to return a function. I could put the *result* of each function (e.g. `mean(.data)`) on the RHS of this `case_when`, but it's important that I don't evaluate any function that isn't intended. Is there a way around this, or a similarly concise way to do a switch case in R, to choose a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are defining two arguments for the function `average` but are passing only one. I think you were trying to call `average(c(1, 2), 'mean')` but this will still not fix the issue. I think `case_when` cannot return functions.

Use a simple `if`/`else` statement.

```
average = function(.data, .avg){
  f <- if(.avg == 'mean') mean
        else if(.avg == 'median') median
  f(.data)
}
```

Or use base R scalar alternative of `case_when` i.e `switch` :

```
average = function(.data, .avg){
 f <- switch(.avg, mean = mean, median = median)
 f(.data)
}
```

For this simple case you can also use `match.fun` :

```
average = function(.data, .avg){
  match.fun(.avg)(.data)
}
```

Use any one of the above function and call it with :

```
average(c(1, 5, 6), 'mean')
#[1] 4
average(c(1, 5, 6), 'median')
#[1] 5
```

Comment: Thanks for picking up on my mistake. I've fixed it. But these are also some good solutions, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, creating a list of functions and then use the data argument while returning the function call:

```
average = function(.data, .avg){
 list_of_funcs <- list('mean' = mean, 'median' = median)
 return(list_of_funcs[[.avg]](.data))
}
class(average)

> average(c(1,2,3,4, 10), 'mean')
# [1] 4
> average(c(1,2,3,4, 10), 'median')
# [1] 3
```

Comment: As I said in the original post, I don't want to evaluate these functions unless they are chosen. This *looks* like it's evaluating them but it's hard to tell with R.

Comment: @Migwell, Edited the post. Sorry was unable to comprehend your question well. Thanks